# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text in Python using websockets for Audio streams

Tags: python-3.6, google-speech-api

Is there a good documentation for streaming audio from client side using JavaScript and websockets and converting it to text using Google Cloud Speech-to-Text in Python?

Answer (score 5):

For client and server using Python you can refer to this [GitHub example](https://github.com/dawntcherian/Google-speech-to-text-python-websocket-server-using-microphone-stream)